# FileMaker Pro pop up values from related table

Tags: portal, filemaker

I have a portal in my contacts table layout that shows related mention in a second "mentions" table. This related table has a relationship to a third "sources" table that I want the user to select from when they view the data in the "mentions" portal of my "contacts" layout. This works for the most part. The problem comes when the user changes the "source" in the portal then attempts to change the "source" in the next portal row t will change the "source" to the last select source regardless to make a selection

any ideas ?

here are some screen shots of how I have it setup

portal and specified field
[image]

and field control setup [image]

and the relationship
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are modifying the value of the source field in the sources table, which is not what you want. You only want to use that data to populate your value list and store the serial number of that source (or the source text) in your mentions table.

1) Create a value list from sources using all values from the sources field.

2) Create a new field in the *Mentions* table called 'source.'

3) Add that field to the portal and remove the current sources field.

4) Apply the value list to your new field.

Comment: so there really is no point in setting a relationship between mentions and sources right ?

Comment: Hmmm , I did what you said and it works except that now the mentions have no source unless I assign them ? where as before because they where built of the relationship it would show them.

Comment: You need to go into 'Manage Database' > 'Define fields' and add a default value (this can be assigned by a calculation if needed). You don't need that relationship for this portal, but you might need it somewhere else. Does that answer your question?

Comment: sort of, just can't figure out how to make the calculation work

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your portal isn't actually the mentions table, but the sources table. Either that or the field that you're using to change the "source" is not in the mentions table, or is not the correct Table Occurrence.

The portal should be based on the Mentions table, and should contain a field in that table that refers to the sources table, not a field from the sources table.

Either way, to diagnose it further, I'd probably need more detail.

Comment: thanks Nick,I added some screen shots to my question in hopes that might lead us in the right direction

Comment: I'm still not having any luck with this did the screen shots help you understand what I'm doing any better or show what I"m doing wrong ?